# SAS adding a prefix to all words in a macro variable

Tags: string, sas, prefix, sas-macro

I am adding a prefix to each word in a macro variable. However, when using my current method, the first word does not receive the prefix. Looking at my code, there is good reason for this as there is no space in front of the word.

The code i use is:

```
%LET independent_vars   =   FF_1 FF_4 FF_7 FF_10;
%LET log_independent_vars = %SYSFUNC(TRANWRD(&independent_vars.,%str( ),%str( ln_)));
%PUT &log_independent_vars.;
```

Current output is:
    FF_1 ln_FF_4 ln_FF_7 ln_FF_10

Expected output is:
    ln_FF_1 ln_FF_4 ln_FF_7 ln_FF_10

I've tried using prxchange but I don't understand it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only the first space is stripped

You can circumvent this problem by adding one 'ln_' in front of your formula

```
%LET independent_vars   =   FF_1 FF_4 FF_7 FF_10;
%LET log_independent_vars = ln_%SYSFUNC(TRANWRD(&independent_vars.,%str( ),%str( ln_)));
%PUT &log_independent_vars.;
```

> ln_FF_1 ln_FF_4 ln_FF_7 ln_FF_10

Comment: oh very nice sir